# Flutter: Show AlertDialog when app is startup

Tags: flutter

I need help with my app. I want to get alertdialog when app is startup. I tried almost everything but nothing is alright. It still throws away similar errors. If I tried in other screens, everything is OK, but in main.dart isnt alright.
I tried Stateless:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showAlert(context));
```

and Stateful:

```
 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_)
......

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
        void initState() {
        super.initState(); 
        Future(_showDialog);
        Timer.run(_showDialog); // Requires import: 'dart:async'
      }
```

and others codes from web.

Errors:

```
> Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Restarted application in 3 059ms.
E/flutter (19353): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found.
E/flutter (19353): MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
E/flutter (19353): The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.
E/flutter (19353): To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
E/flutter (19353): The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
E/flutter (19353):   MyApp
E/flutter (19353): The ancestors of this widget were:
E/flutter (19353):   [root]
E/flutter (19353): #0      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (19353): #1      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations
E/flutter (19353): #2      showDialog
E/flutter (19353): #3      _MyAppState.initState.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (19353): #4      _MyAppState.initState.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (19353): #5      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
E/flutter (19353): #6      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
E/flutter (19353): #7      SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (19353): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1420:47)
E/flutter (19353): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (19353): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (19353): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (19353): #12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter (19353): #13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (19353): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1260:23)
E/flutter (19353): #15     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (19353): #16     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter (19353): #17     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter (19353): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (19353):
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this code in `initState`

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
          child: AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            content: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Here is the full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(isDialogShow: false), // here pass parameter
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isDialogShow;
  HomePage({this.isDialogShow});
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.isDialogShow) // here you check 
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
          child: AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            content: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Alert dialog in app start up"),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: And sure that you use material app.

Comment: Dont work. I still have the same error. Code: 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {

Comment: updated my answer please check the `full source code` part

Comment: `Jahidul Islam` thank you very much, but I have other problem when I return to main.dart the dialog box still starts. I want it to run only once, at startup. How?

Comment: you can pass with parameter like `isDialogBoxShow`, if it is true then show it otherwise don't show and updated my answer please check it.

Comment: Error:  This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: HomePage.isDialogShow

Comment: isDialogShow makes final that means `final bool isDialogShow;`

Comment: everything is OK, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the MaterialApp() widget as the entry to your app?

From the error info, it seems you are calling your widgets directly without this implementation of the MaterialApp widget. the _showDialog method works with this widget so you need to provide the MaterialApp as the entry, usually like this:

```
// your runapp function like this

runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   return MaterialApp(
     child: SplashScreen(), //or some other screens you would like to show
);

then you can be sure that your code will work.
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I have almost everywhere.